# ¿Cargar un combobox desde código (sin DB) asignando un valor a cada uno?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¿Cómo puedo cargar datos desde código y por detrás valores para cada uno?

```
Valor   Tipo
  1     Perro
  2     Gato
  3     Ave
```

He tratado con el siguiente código:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(1, "Perro");
```

Comment: Mira esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7721089/4092887) a ver si te sirve.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave ya lo revise antes del post, quiero si usar un dataset ni parametros de la Db, solo en codigo internet poner un valor a cada opcion

Comment: Solo insertalos... cada elemento que agregas tiene un indice con el que puedes hacer `comboBox1.Items.IndexOf(el_elemento_que_quieras);` y te devuelve un entero con el valor _(Empezando en cero)_ que necesitas.

Comment: @NaCl eso tambien lo intente, a no ser que tienes otro punto de vista que no entiendo en tu ejemplo, ponlo como respuesta

Comment: Lo primero es que no entiendo a qué te refieres con "Por detrás valores para cada uno"... Así que por eso te sugerí lo que dije en el comentario anterior.

Comment: @NaCl en un combobox muestran los tipos y no valores, con lo por detras me referia a no mostrar los valores si no los tipos

Comment: o mas claro, selecciono a Ave en mi combobox y en un mensaje emergente (MessageBox) aparesca el Valor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public partial class Form : Form
        {
        private void ItemsCombobox()
            {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(new ClassItems("Perro", 1));
            comboBox1.Items.Add(new ClassItems("Gato", 2));
            comboBox1.Items.Add(new ClassItems("Ave", 3));
            }
        public FormXX()
            {
            InitializeComponent();
            ItemsCombobox();
            }
        private void btnVerDatos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            ClassItems ItemCmb = (ClassItems)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
            MessageBox.Show(ItemCmb.Name);
            MessageBox.Show(ItemCmb.Value.ToString());
            }
        }
```

tengo una clase ClassItems

```
    class ClassItems
        {
        public string Name;
        public int Value;

        public ClassItems(string name, int value)
            {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
            }
        public override string ToString()
            {
            return Name;
            }
        }
```

Solucion Cercana : [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222118/adding-data-to-a-combobox-not-bound-data/StackOverFlow)